# Jed.js - How do I correctly create a Jed instance?

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, gettext

I'm trying use jed.js as a solution for i18n in my project.

I'm having trouble understanding the options passed to the Jed constructor.

Docs say that I should pass in a domain and locale_data object.
However, in the locale_data, there is another key with the domain value.
And again, under that, there is an empty key (i.e. "") which has another domain key and the domain as the value.

Here's an excerpt from the docs:

```
var i18n = new Jed({
    // You can choose to set the domain at instantiation time
    // If you don't, then "messages" will be used by default
    "domain" : "the_domain",
    // This is the translation data, which is often generated by
    // a po2json converter. You would ideally have one per locale
    // and only pull in the locale_data that you need.
    "locale_data" : {
        // This is the domain key
        "the_domain" : {
            // The empty string key is used as the configuration
            // block for each domain
            "" : {
                // Domain name
                "domain" : "the_domain"
            }
        }
    }
});
```

1. What is the meaning of the domain, and why is it repeated so many times?
2. Do I need a new Jed instance for every domain?
3. How does the domain relate to the language?